# what order do events fire on radio button click?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, cross-browser

I know this is different between browsers; e.g. If I attach a function to the onclick and onchange event of a radio button, then click on it, Chrome fires onchange then onclick, while Firefox does the opposite.

Is there a resource anyone knows of that breaks down this firing order by browser?

Comment: FYI: Even using jQuery the events come in a different order depending on the browser.

Comment: Afaik it's not possible to change the firing order, but you could check `event.type`, and "redirect" to the wanted eventhandler.

Comment: I don't really need to *change* the order (annoying as that disparity might be) - I would just like to know what to expect, and wondered if anyone else had mapped it out, before I run a bunch of tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle that will tell you if you run it in each browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/BUkHz/

```
<label for="myRadio">Radio Button</label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio"/>
<label for="myRadio">Radio Button 2</label><input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio2"/>




var myRadio = document.getElementById('myRadio');
    var myRadio2 = document.getElementById('myRadio2');

    myRadio.addEventListener('change', interceptRadioEvent);
    myRadio.addEventListener('click', interceptRadioEvent);
    myRadio2.addEventListener('change', interceptRadioEvent);
    myRadio2.addEventListener('click', interceptRadioEvent);

    function interceptRadioEvent(e){
        //do anything else you want to here...
        radioEventHandler(e);
    }

    function radioEventHandler(e){
        console.log(e.type);
    }
```

I have a hunch that the order depends on what you're doing - for example if you only have one radio button on first click it will be : change, click then further clicks would be 'click' only as it responds to the click but can't unset it.

I hope that helps.

On a Mac :

Chrome:
change then click

Safari:
change then click

iOS(6):
change then click

Comment: I was hoping someone else had already tested it out for me - but yeah, you're right, something like this will totally map out those firing orders.

Comment: It seems that didn't worked for me. event I checked the code that you posted on fiddle.
chrome 31.0.16 version : Change -> click
Firfox 25.0.1 version : click-> change
and yes forgot to mention os is Windows but i guess that should not be the problem

Comment: Just tied it and I get 1. click 2. change. So this got changed between this answer and 2020 (Chrome 80 on Mac)