# Check if the radio button is changed by the keyboard or mouse

Tags: jquery

Is possible to tell how a radio button was selected, i.e. if the user used the keyboard or the mouse to click the radio button?

Comment: Could you detail your question a bit? It is unclear to me what your exact question is

Comment: you can do this by checking for ASCII value.

Comment: @RobTillie, I have a group of i.e. three radio buttons, I need to know if the selected radiobutton was changed clicking on it or using the TAB and the arrows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that is not doable with a change event.
I resolved in this way, If someone knows a more elegant way let me know:

```
<input name="text" type="input">
<input name="radioButton" type="radio" value="1"> 1
<input name="radioButton" type="radio" value="2"> 2
<input name="radioButton" type="radio" value="3"> 3
```

```js
var radioButtonValue;
$('input[name="radioButton"]').on("click", function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value !== radioButtonValue) {
        if (e.clientX === 0 && e.clientY === 0) {
            console.log("keyboard");
        } else {
            console.log("mouse");
        };
        radioButtonValue = value;        
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gy59n3u6/1/

Comment: Works in Opera and Firefox. In IE (11), it works for bare radio buttons, but if you wrap a radio button in a label (and you should always provide a label around the caption!) IE sends back bizarre negative co-ordinates if you click on the label, but works if you click directly on the radio button.[PRETEND LINE BREAK][PRETEND LINE BREAK]This is good enough for me, as I just wanted to be able to switch focus on click (to whatever the radio button is selecting) but not switch focus if you select the radio button with the keyboard else you can't step through them. Evil no doubt, but I like it!

Answer (score 5):

There is no cross-browser solution for detecting a 'real mouse click' vs 'a click event triggered by the keyboard'.

Ideally, we would check the [MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) value. Unfortunately only IE11 & Edge will properly record a value of '-1' for a keyboard click. At this time, all other browsers will record a value of '0' for any type of click.

Another option is to check the [MouseEvent.pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) & [MouseEvent.pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY) values. In Chrome, keyboard clicks will have a value of 0 for both these values. Firefox will also have a value of 0 but it will also factor in the `$(window).scrollLeft()` & `$(window).scrollTop()` values. Unfortunately Safari will not record consistent `pageX`/`pageY` values for keyboard events and IE will record the exact location of the mouse when the keyboard click event was fired.

The best cross browser solution is to add a [mouseup](https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) event listener to your radio inputs and their associated labels and set a flag when it is triggered. When a keyboard toggles a radio button the [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event is fired but the `mouseup` event is not. So if you set a flag on `mouseup` and check this flag on `click`, you should be able to detect if the mouse clicked the radio button.

```
var clickedByMouse = false;
$('label, input[type="radio"]').mouseup(function(e) {
    clickedByMouse = true;
});
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if(clickedByMouse){
        console.log("mouse");
        //Reset flag
        clickedByMouse = false;
    }else{
        console.log("keyboard");
    }
});
```

This solution worked cross-browser, including Safari and older IE versions. You may notice I included the `label` tag with the `mouseup` event, this is because `label` tags can toggle a radio input. They either can be wrapped around a radio input or linked to a radio input using the `for` attribute.

Above I mentioned that there is no cross-browser solution. This is because I began testing this solution with screen readers, specifically [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS), and discovered another issue.

[JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS) by default will not let you use the arrow keys to toggle between radio buttons of the same group. You have to press the enter key to enter a special 'forms mode' and then you can use the arrow keys as intended. Pressing the enter key will however toggle the radio button and [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS) will trigger a `mouseup` & `click` event on the radio button. So the above code will not work effectively.

```
var clickedByMouse = false;
$('label, input[type="radio"]').mouseup(function(e) {
    var keyboardPageX = (e.pageX === 0 || e.pageX === $(window).scrollLeft()) ? true : false,
        keyboardPageY = (e.pageY === 0 || e.pageY === $(window).scrollTop()) ? true : false;

    if((keyboardPageX && keyboardPageY) || (e.button === -1)){
       console.log("keyboard mouseup");
    }else{
       clickedByMouse = true;
    }
});
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if(clickedByMouse){
        console.log("mouse");
        //Reset flag
        clickedByMouse = false;
    }else{
        console.log("keyboard");
    }
});
```

The solution above also uses the [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent)'s `pageX`, `pageY` and `button` values to double check for a keyboard click event. Depending on the browser being used, it will work with [JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS).

Comment: e.pageX and e.pageY are not 0 in Safari when triggered by keyboard, however offsetX and offsetY are.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a listener for when the user presses space bar (I assume that's the keyboard command you are listening to)

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 32){
        $("input[name=someRadioGroup]:radio").change(function () {
            console.log("Space bar was pressed to change the radio button"); 
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4pjnrcoz/1/

Thanks to @Mysteryos, he added the HTML to this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4pjnrcoz/3

Comment: @Mysteryos Yes it does.  You need to TAB to the select options first.  Then hit space bar and watch the console. It's doing a bit of strangeness when you use the arrow keys to switch between the two, but it still shows when you use the keyboard rather than the mouse

Comment: @Mysteryos, No thank you - You placed the HTML in there that I didn't want to do ;)

Comment: @ntgCleaner it does not work for me, once the the change event is fired, the console log is shown on every change, no matter if it was made by the mouse or by the arrow keys

Comment: There are several problems with this approach: 1) it is listening at the document level for ALL keyboard events, and checking if the spacebar was pressed, which could happen when the event is not related to the radio button. (Also, major scope problem). 2) it uses this potentially incorrect event to set the onChange listener, which will fire for ANY change event on the radio input, whether arrow keys or mouse clicks. This does not answer the original question in any regard.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580057/what-order-do-events-fire-on-radio-button-click) is a pretty good discussion on the Radio buttons Click and Change events.

One thing you can do is, create a click event handler and set a flag, use it later on a different (callback maybe!) function to identify if the change has been triggered by Keyboard or Mouse Click!

Answer (score 1):

[`event.detail`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) is another possible indicator if `click` is caused by keyboard, indicating click number. That gives better cross-browser solution, compared to `event.x/y`.

```
<input name="letter" type="radio" value="a"> a
<input name="letter" type="radio" value="b"> b
<input name="letter" type="radio" value="c"> c

<script>
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!e.detail) console.log('Keyboard click')
  else console.log('Mouseclick')
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="radio" id="radiobtn">

 $("#radiobtn").keyup(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 32) { 
       alert("Space bar was pressed");
    }
    else {
       alert("mouse click");
    }
 });
```

Comment: Radio button's status can be changed by keys other than "Space bar" as well. Also, the key code for space bar should be 32 not 13!

Comment: Oops my mistake. I had edited my question. Thanks for alerting bugs.

Comment: @user254153, I need to know if the change was made using the TAB and the arrow keys or by clicking the mouse