# How to call Javascript Function on radio button click not on focus

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have a table which contains a radio button in every row. I am calling a JavaScript function `onclick` event on radio button like this

```
<input type="radio" id="rdbSelect" name="Select" onclick="MyFunction()" />
```

But when I press `Down/Up` arrow in keyboard, focus goes to `Next/Previous` radio button function calls again.

I want that function to be called only when radio button is clicked by mouse, not on focus.

Here is my Code

HTML

```
<div style="width:400px">
    <table class="style1" id="Table1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="rdbSelect" name="Select" onclick="Test()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and JavaScript

```
function CreateGrid() {
    var Grid = document.getElementById('Table1')
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var newrow = Grid.rows[Grid.rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
        newrow.cells[0].innerText;
        newrow.cells[1].children[0].value = '';
        newrow.cells[2].children[0].value = '';
        Grid.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild(newrow);
    }
}

function Test() {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to consider onChange event I suppose..

Comment: Hi @RayonDabre Thanks for your kind interest, I tried onchange but result is same :(

Comment: Can you provide entire html and JS code ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question, Please check

Comment: Can you provide jsFiddle replicating your issue because as i understand your issue, this isn't expected behaviour  `I want that function call only when Radio button clicked by mouse, not on focus.` Setting focus using keyboard doesn't fire click event as i'm aware of

Comment: As a side note, your rendered HTML using `CreateGrid()` method is invalid, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: If a solution worked for you, can you mark an answer as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you try this

```
 <input type="radio" name="rd1" id="red" onchange="myFunction()">select
```

for ex:-

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="red" onchange="myFunction()">select<br>
<script>

function myFunction() {
alert("radio selected");
}

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @mukesh, I tried onchange event but still the same result.

Comment: Dear @  Shaiwal Tripathi this code is running code .please tell me your browser that you used and where you apply this code in simple html or in other .

Comment: The problem with onChange, is that it fires whenever it is *changed*, which includes both focus changes AND click changes. Not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Check the answer posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400670/3780922

It details all the cross-browser problems associated with handling click/change events, and walks through where the mouse-event trick (as shown below) fails.

Focus is a tough problem, because once the radio group (all radios with the same name) is focused, the arrow keys will change the value, which fires the `change` event AND the `click` event, which is done via the browser for compatibility with keyboard navigation.

a simple but non-cross-browser solution is as follows:

```
$('input[name="radioButton"]').on("click", function(e) {

    if (e.clientX === 0 && e.clientY === 0) {
        console.log("keyboard");
    } else {
        console.log("mouse");
    };
}
```

Comment: note that this needs to be the onClick function, not the onChange; the `change` event object does not include the required attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
document.getElementById("rdbSelect").click()
```

Comment: What browser you are using

Comment: Your code is working quite good in my browser,without any problem,Currently I am using chrome,and is also works on IE8

Answer (score 0):

I has resolved it using something [like this (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/0zc15cba/1/):

> If the event keyboard down is called (called even first) so cancel all the events

```
<input type="radio" name="aradio" onkeydown="changeEvent(this,event)" onclick="changeEvent(this, event)" />Option one<br/>
<input type="radio" name="aradio" onkeydown="changeEvent(this,event)" onclick="changeEvent(this, event)" />Option two

window.changeEvent = function(element, event){
  if(event.keyCode == 0){
    console.log("click event");
    //alert("click event");
  }else{
    console.log("keyboard event");
    //alert("keyboard event");
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

[or using jquery (on jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/deFreitas/eheto8x6/1/)

```
<input type="radio" name="aradio" />Option one<br/>
<input type="radio" name="aradio" />Option two

$("input[name=aradio]")
    .on("click", changeEvent)
    .on("keydown", changeEvent);

function changeEvent(event){
  if(event.originalEvent.keyCode == 0){
    console.log("click event");
    //alert("click event");
  }else{
    console.log("keyboard event");
    //alert("keyboard event");
    event.preventDefault();
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can Write this Move you javascript code to head section

```
<script>
function CreateGrid() {
    var Grid = document.getElementById('Table1')
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        var newrow = Grid.rows[Grid.rows.length - 1].cloneNode(true);
        newrow.cells[0].innerText;
        newrow.cells[1].children[0].value = '';
        newrow.cells[2].children[0].value = '';
        Grid.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild(newrow);
    }
}

function Test() {
    alert("Hello");
}
</script>

<div style="width:400px">
    <table class="style1" id="Table1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="text2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="rdbSelect" name="Select" onclick="Test()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```