# Switching between radio inputs with keyboard triggers onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button

You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vt0u2ddk/

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].onclick = function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    console.log('clicked', e.target.value);
  };
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <input name="auto" value="foo" type="radio" checked>foo</label>
  <input name="auto" value="bar" type="radio">bar</label>
  <input name="auto" value="ming" type="radio">ming</label>
</div>
```

If you click on a radio button (not the label) first, you get an alert for a click event. If you then use the arrow keys to switch the selection of the radio list, each time a click event gets triggered. Why? I'm using my keyboard and not my mouse. Is there a explanation and/or workaround for this?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think that's normal behaviour. But you can work arround it if you read this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947302/check-if-the-radio-button-is-changed-by-the-keyboard-or-mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `mouseup` event instead. The `click` event considers switching radio buttons to be a left click (for some reason, verify this by checking `e.button`), but `mouseup` properly recognizes the difference between the two and will not fire when using the keyboard. My testing seems to verify that `mouseup` properly recognizes raising your finger from a touch event too, but I'm not 100% on that point.

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].onmouseup = function(e) {
    alert('clicked: ' + e.button);
    console.log('clicked', e.target.value);
  };
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <input name="auto" value="foo" type="radio" checked>foo</label>
  <input name="auto" value="bar" type="radio">bar</label>
  <input name="auto" value="ming" type="radio">ming</label>
</div>
```